# The exact meaning and synonym of "inherited wisdom"

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering what **"inherited wisdom"** means.

Furthermore, it would be appreciated if someone please provide a definite synonym for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wisdom" = "knowledge" or "way of thinking about {something | things}"
"Inherited" = "passed down from one's predecessors (especially ancestors)"

In this case, the "inheritance" is usually "passed down" by people telling stories while they are alive, not by bequeathing books as part of a dead person's will.

Depending on the context, the information could be passed down within a family, within a village or tribe, or within a company (from more experienced co-workers to less experienced co-workers).

Some possible synonyms:

> Lore passed down from one's ancestors.
>   Old-fashioned advice.
>   Plain old common sense.
>   Tribal lore.

An example:

- The *hadiths* are a collection of "inherited wisdom" in Muslim societies.